# How to stop all videos when a new video is played?

Tags: javascript, html, video

On my page, I have many videos and I want to stop the video when playing another video in HTML5.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" id="videos">
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <div class="card border-0 text-center">
            <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/webm">
                <object data="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                    <embed src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                </object>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <div class="card border-0 text-center">
            <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/webm">
                <object data="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                    <embed src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                </object>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <div class="card border-0 text-center">
            <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/webm">
                <object data="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                    <embed src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                </object>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <div class="card border-0 text-center">
            <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4" type="video/webm">
                <object data="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                    <embed src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/1659416196.mp4">
                </object>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(event){
        document.querySelectorAll("#videos").forEach((video) => {
            video.onplay = function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                document.querySelectorAll("video").forEach((playing) => {
                    if(video === playing)
                        playing.play();
                    else
                        playing.pause();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to stop all div#videos videos (here I have taken only 4, but there are several videos) from running on the current page when a new video is clicked. At one point in time, only one video should run. I have gone through the documentation.

Comment: Doesn't your code work?

Comment: Why. My codes work. Only I want to stop all videos when a video is played.

Comment: So why do you ask?

Comment: Please read my question carefully. (How to stop all videos when a new video is played?)

Comment: Your selector seem incorrect. For instance `#videos` is  selecting the row with the id `videos`. Doing a for each doesn't give you a video, it gives you a row. And then you are looking for elements with the class `inlineVideo`, which i don't see any on your html example...
To stop all videos, when a video play starts (you can add an event listener for that), loop through all videos and if they are not the videos that triggered the event (check the `event.target`), then stop and rewind them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#videos video` seems to be a much better selector

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll("#videos video").forEach((video) => {
    video.onplay = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.querySelectorAll("#videos video").forEach((playing) => {
        if (video === playing)
          playing.play();
        else
          playing.pause();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="row" id="videos">
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card border-0 text-center">
      <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card border-0 text-center">
      <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card border-0 text-center">
      <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card border-0 text-center">
      <video poster="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/videos/1659416196.png" controls="">
                <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```